# Stopping a bound service

Tags: android, binding, service

I have a large texting app that I'm using a service to handle most operations. The app has about 10 or so different Activities which bind to the service to perform varying operations. Every activity binds to the service in onResume, and Unbinds in onStop (I also null out the reference here as well). The service also receives the startService command to start when the app first opens.

I'm trying to implement a kill switch, so that when a text is sent from a certain number, with a certain keyword, it will shut the app down, except for a seperate activity, and license service to listen for the reactivation text.

The main texting service is also running as a foreground service, so it shows in the notification bar. Right now, when it gets the deactivation text, it never removes itself from the notification bar. I can manually take it out by running stopForeground(), but that only takes it out of the notification bar. If the app receives the activation text, the service gets the onStartCommand, but not onCreate (which is where I set it to a foreground service).

The service also never appears to call the onDestroy() method. I've read around here and other places that when you use startService AND bind to the service, you must first make sure to unbind the service, then run stopService. As I said above, I'm unbinding the service in all the activities that bind in onStop, so if none of these activities are visible, they shouldn't be bound. I am also calling stopService as well.

It seems as though there is something still being held by the service, but I'm at a loss as to what. I have 6 seperate threads which exist in this service, which I make sure to destroy before attempting to stop it (as well as unregistering the sms receiver).

Any ideas on how to diagnose this further?

Comment: on a "kill switch" did you first unbound service and then stop the service , because you only put unbound code in onStop method only

Comment: What happens is that a seperate activity is opened, which doesn't bind to the service at all. It stops the service from this activity, or at least tries to.

Comment: According to me , you can stop service from another activity which did not bind with service.